# Django - Conditional Rendering In Templates

Tags: python, django, templates

I need some help conditionally rendering data in a modal pop up window on my site.

What I want to do:
When the user clicks on the "make reservation" button, I want to display this in the modal window

```
<h3 style="margin-top:20px;">Choose dates</h3>
                    <div style="margin-top:20px;" class="pick-dates-div">
                        <form method="GET" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
                            {{ form.as_p }}
                            <button type="submit" class="form-btn save btn btn-default">Make A Reservation</button>
                        </form>
                        <button style="margin-top: 25px;" class="btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" data-toggle="modal"
                            data-target="#inquiryModal">More
                            Questions ?</button>
                    </div>
```

Then the user can pick the dates from the date picker and press the "make a reservation" button ( which is a GET request ), the page refreshes and I want to display only this in the same modal window :

```
<h1>Start Date: {{ date_start }}</h1>
    <h1>End Date: {{ date_end }}</h1>
    <h1>Price Per Day: ${{ price_per_day }}$</h1>
    <h1>Total: ${{ total_price }}$</h1>
    <form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
       <a href=""> <button href="www.facebook.com" type="submit" class="form-btn save btn btn-default">Confirm Reservation</button></a>
    </form>
```

After that the user submits the form ( POST request ) and I want to display a text :

```
<h3> Thank you for your reservation </3>
```

What would be the ideal way to achieve this ?
Thank you stack

Comment: seems like what you trying to do would involve ajax [ajax-with-django](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html)

Answer (score 2):

The ideal way to achieve this is by using JavaScript.

One of the many methods this could be achieved is by rendering all the three views inside separate containers in a modal and then hiding the next two using javascript.

> You can use **element.style.display = 'none'** to hide and
>   **element.style.display = 'block'** to show the content inside the element container.

Once the user clicks on "make reservation" button, hide/show the required containers to achieve the desired result.

Do not forget to secure your website by using proper validation on the server end. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer !
Unfortunately I forgot to mention, it all has to be done in the backend.

Comment: Any specific reasons for why it needs to be done in the backend? If that is the case, you can use an endpoint to fetch the html and populate the empty containers as and when user clicks on the buttons